# How to remove duplicate line by perl or bash?

Tags: perl, bash

I have a list:

```
asd@domain.com
fff@domain.com
yyy@domain.com
ttt@test.com
rrr@test.com
fff@test.com
yyy@my.com
yyy@my.com
```

How it possible to do this:

if in whole list we see three or more email with same domain - all duplicates except first one need to remove.

```
Output:

asd@domain.com
ttt@test.com
yyy@my.com
yyy@my.com
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Email::Address;

my %data;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($addr) = Email::Address->parse($line =~ /^(\S+)/);
    push @{ $data{ $addr->host } }, $addr->original;
}

for my $addrs (values %data) {
    if (@$addrs > 2) {
        print "$addrs->[0]\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$_\n" for @$addrs;
    }
}

__DATA__
asd@domain.com
fff@domain.com
yyy@domain.com
ttt@test.com
rrr@test.com
fff@test.com
yyy@my.com
yyy@my.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -s 's/@/@\t/g' test.txt | uniq -f 1 | sed -s 's/@\t/@/g'
```

The first sed separates the email in 2 fields (name + domain) with a tab character, so that uniq can skip the first field when removing the duplicate domains, and the last sed removes the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled why your example output contains `yyy@my.com` twice but assume it is a mistake.

As long as there are no issues with trailing space characters or more complex forms of email addresses you can do this simply in Perl with

```
perl -aF@ -ne 'print unless $seen{$F[1]}++' myfile
```

**output**

```
asd@domain.com
ttt@test.com
yyy@my.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\([^@]*@\([^\n]*\)\)\n.*\2/\1/;ta;P;D' file
asd@domain.com
ttt@test.com
yyy@my.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the order, just use sort:

```
sort -t '@' -u -k 2,2 your_file
```

If you do mind the order, do

```
gawk '{print NR "@" $0}' your_file | sort -t '@' -u -k 3,3 | sort -t '@' -k 1,1n | cut -d \@ -f 2-
```